# VMPlayer doesn't load modules anymore

Tags: drivers, kernel, vmware, 18.10

I'm struggeling with my VMWare Workstation.

Environment: Kubuntu 18.10 with Kernel `4.18.0-12-generic` on a Lenovo Thinkpad

Situation: While the notebook runs with kernel version `4.18.0-11-generic`, I can start vmplayer, it compiles (if needed) its kernel module (vmmon.ko and vmnet.ko) and then starts the virtual machine without any problem.

After updating to kernel version `4.18.0-12-generic`, vmplayer compiles again both modules, however the modules cannot be loaded anymore. Loading the modules manually leads to the following error message:

`root@koehn-ThinkPad# modprobe -v vmmon 
insmod /lib/modules/4.18.0-12-generic/misc/vmmon.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vmmon': Operation not permitted`

If I reboot the system and start again `4.18.0-11-generic`, everything is fine again.

Does anybody have an idea?

BTW, I also tried `4.18.0-13-generic`. The result is identical to `-12`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have UEFI Secure Boot enabled.
There are two main choices:

1. disable Secure Boot
2. enable your kernel models to be signed for secure boot

Option 1 is simpler-- you'll want to go into you BIOS menu and disable secure boot.  How this is done varies by computer, but typically you'll need to press F2 or DEL at the first startup screen.  Once in there, you'll need to look for the "secure boot" option and turn it off.

Option 2 means that you need to generate a certificate and then teach your computer to trust it.  That's covered by this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot

Comment: Thanks for this hint. You're totally right. To check it quickly, I used option 1, now it is working again. The only thing what I really don't understand: what has changed between the two patch level -11 and -12 which prohibits starting of unsigned kernel modules? I see no hint in the ubuntu kernel change log...

Comment: Same issue and same solution helped on HP Elitebook. Disabled secure boot in bios and vmware is running now.